# Custom "html_email_template_name" not working

Tags: django

I am trying to customise the password reset email sent by the application without success. My application ignores my declaration and keeps sending this one: django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html.

This is my relevant url.py declaration:

```
# Password reset
path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name = 'account/password_reset_form.html', html_email_template_name='account/password_reset_email.html', success_url = reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_done')), name = 'password_reset'),
```

The file templates/account/password_reset_email.html exists and has contents.

Many thanks, I am going nuts over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong view variable it is

```
email_template_name
```

Django docs regarding [PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)